# Syntax for combining NSURL and normal string?

Tags: objective-c

What syntax could I use to make this work?
`UIImage` with `NSURL`

`banner.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/file.file"+placemark.administrativeArea+@".png"]]];`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This way:

```
banner.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/file.file%@.png",placemark.administrativeArea]]]];
```

Don't use so much statement in one line.
IT has several problem like Difficult to understand and Hard to find error.

I suggest this way:

```
NSString *imgStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/file.file%@.png",placemark.administrativeArea];
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imgStr];
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
banner.image = img;
```

But it depend on u.

Good day..